# Trigger Follow-up intent from intent other than parent intent- API.AI

Tags: dialogflow-es

[image]
I have one intent named Call with two follow up intents Yes & No.
I  have one more intent OrderChange. As a respone in OrderChange intent, bot tells asks user if users wants to call customer support or not. Based on user's yes/no, i want to trigger Call intent's follow-up yes or no intent. 
.
How can I call follow up intent of some intent from intent other than it's parent?
I explored API.ai documentation, but not able to find anything solving my query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Followup Intents are really just Intents with a specific Context set for them as an Incoming Context. You can do the same thing without using Followup Intents, but instead just using regular Intents and specifying the incoming Context to use.

So, to use your example, both the "Call Customer Support?" Intent and the "Call" Intent could set an outgoing context of "call_question". You can then create a context called "call.yes" that takes an incoming context of "call_question" and has sample phrases such as "yes", "yup", "sure", "please", and so forth. (And, similarly, a "call.no" context which has the same incoming context and has sample phrases such as "no", "never", "no thank you", etc.)

Comment: Yup you are right.If I design these intents as regular intents, I'll achieve the desired result. But is it possible to trigger follow-up intents from intent which is not parent intent of those follow-up intent?

Comment: No, because then they wouldn't be "follow-up". Why do you specifically want them to be followup intents?

Comment: Actully there were some follow-up intents which I wanted to use from another intent. just to avoid duplication. However, I've made those intents as separate intents as you suggested. They can be accessed now. Thanks you.

Comment: Glad it has helped. If so, accepting and/or upvoting the answer is always appreciated.